# How to solve the org.apache.solr.common.SolrException in solr?

Tags: php, apache, solr, lucene

I am getting the following error when indexing in **solr** using **DIH**.

Error is

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=4820044] Error adding field 'brand_id'='java.math.BigInteger:4633' msg=For input string: "java.math.BigInteger:4633"
```

My schema for amount field is

```
<field name="brand_id" type="tlong" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Please help ..

Answer (score 0):

You try to add the String `Java.math.BigInteger:4633` as the field value, but you should only add the value `4633`.
I tried this with Java (with the SolrJ library) since the error comes from a Java object. This document will lead to the error being thrown (when it is indexed):

```
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.setField("brand_id", "Java.math.BigInteger:4633");
```

If you replace the second line with:

```
doc.setField("brand_id", new BigInteger("4633"));
```

or

```
doc.setField("brand_id", 4633);
```

it should work.
You tagged the question as being related to PHP but I cannot help you with the PHP part without being able to look at your code or knowing how the Java object makes it into your Solr document or index request.
You might be able to use a var_dump or some other way of logging/debugging in PHP to see what you're trying to index.